# how to sort DataTable column values?

Tags: c#-4.0, datatable

**In my c# DataTable data is like this.**

---

***Col1***

---

1234 - Siva

3445 - Ram

78454 - Anand

343 - Raj

454 - Balu

**I need out put like this**

---

***Col1***

---

78454 - Anand

454 - Balu

3445 - Ram

343 - Raj

1234 - Siva

**How to sort results based on text after '-' character in the column of DataTable in c#**

Comment: If i do something like this, i'd create a buffer column and for each row i'd put what after `-` into it then sort by that column.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with LINQ

```
var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("UserName");

dt.Rows.Add("1234 - Siva");
dt.Rows.Add("3445 - Ram");
dt.Rows.Add("78454 - Anand");
dt.Rows.Add("343 - Raj");
dt.Rows.Add("454 - Balu");

// dtNew will be new DataTable with sorted lines
var dtNew = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => ((string)x["UserName"]).Substring(((string)x["UserName"]).IndexOf("-") + 1).Trim()).CopyToDataTable();
```

I guess you need 2 namespaces for this

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
```